# k_fold value making fell out of the sample SVM class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opencv, svm, emgucv

i have a problem with k_fold value for SVM class in c# (using emgucv). all of number value just making exception as below :

> Emgu.CV.Util.CvException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233088
>   Message=OpenCV: While cross-validation one or more of the classes have
>   been fell out of the sample. Try to enlarge 
>   Source=Emgu.CV   ErrorMessage=While cross-validation one or more of
>   the classes have been fell out of the sample. Try to enlarge

enlarge/ change k_fold value is useless. please help me to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve with it `model.Train(datalatih, kelas, null, null, s)`. This is my code

```
using (SVM model = new SVM())
            {
                SVMParams s = new SVMParams();
                s.KernelType = Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.SVM_KERNEL_TYPE.LINEAR;
                s.SVMType = Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.SVM_TYPE.C_SVC;
                s.C = 1;
                s.TermCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(100, 0.00001);

                // Lakukan pelatihan
                model.Train(datalatih, kelas, null, null, s);

                // Tes Uji SVM
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                {
                    datauji.Data[0, i] = uji[i];
                }
                float hasil = model.Predict(datauji);

                return Tuple.Create((int)hasil);
            }
```